# How do I get a value from another page and output it to a selectlist? JAVASCRIPT

Tags: javascript

I have several input elements in which I enter the name of the book author and the book title. This data should appear in a selectlist that is on a different page. I have to pass values from one page to another, but I don't know how to do it in JavaScript. Could you show me how to do it?

**HTML**

```
 <div class="child">
          <input id="item" type="text" placeholder="Add book" required>
          <input id="item2" type="text" placeholder="Add author" required>

          <select id="mySelect" class="block">
            <option>JS Part 1</option>
            <option>JS Part 2</option>
            <option>HTML + CSS book</option>
            <option>Bootstrap</option>

          </select>
          <select id="mySelect2" class="block">
              <option>Author 1</option>
              <option>Author 2</option>
              <option>Author 3</option>
              <option>Author 4</option>

            </select>
          <input type="submit" id="send" class="block">

          </div>
```

**JS**

```
    var inp = document.getElementById("item");
    inp.value = "Book Title";
    var inp2 = document.getElementById("item2");
    inp2.value = "Author name"; 
    var itemsArray = localStorage.getItem('items') ? 
    JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('items')) : [];

    send.onclick = function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    let name = {
      obj: "ID: ",
      obj2: " Book: ",
      obj3: " Author: " 
    }

    var li = document.getElementsByClassName("me"); 
    var count = li.length;
    console.log(count);

    var sel = document.getElementById('mySelect').selectedIndex;
    var options = document.getElementById('mySelect').options;
    var sel2 = document.getElementById('mySelect2').selectedIndex;
    var options2 = document.getElementById('mySelect2').options;
    var string = name.obj + (count + 1) + " | " + name.obj2 + inp.value + " | " + name.obj3 + inp2.value;


    itemsArray.push(string);
    localStorage.setItem('items', JSON.stringify(itemsArray));
}
```

Comment: Please show your code (your attempt). I'm 99.9% sure that if you don't, you will get downvoted and leave without an answer.

Comment: Have you written your code? If yes please show your code...

Comment: You can use ajax or url parameters for sending data to second page.

Comment: I have edit my post, please open my question

Comment: if you added it in the localstorage then access it on next page whats the matter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

on submit add data in localstorage

```
var itemsArray = localStorage.getItem('items') ? 
JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('items')) : {authors:[],books:[]};
itemsArray.authors.push(inp);
itemsArray.books.push(inp2);
```

then on next page you can do is

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) 
{
console.log("DOM fully loaded ");
let data=JSON.parse(localstorage.getItem('items'))
let select1="";
data.authors.map(author=>{
  select1+="<option>"+author+"</option>"
})
//populate in input fields accordingly
 document.getElementById("slect1").innerHTML=select1 //same way you can do this for book also
}
```